# Jquery ccs3 clock 360° = 1second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, clock

Here is my problem. I'd like my image to be progressively animated so that it turns 360° in one second. So 1deg every 3ms does 360deg every 1000ms. For now nothing happen :( .

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

CSS:

```
#sec {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 300px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="sec" src="sec-02.png" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var srotate = "rotate(1deg)";
        $("#sec").css({
            "-moz-transform": srotate,
            "-webkit-transform": srotate
        });
    }, 3);
});​
```

Comment: Also good to note that setInterval has a minimum delay. It is higher than 3ms, but may vary between browsers depending on the version. It's somewhere between 4ms and 10ms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not incrementing the amount of rotation so you are continuously setting it to 1 degree.

I've made [a fiddle of a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/X5QSa/) (using a kitten as a clock!)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted to do but still don't understand the i trick.
Ok i understand ;) did not noticed the i++. Thank you again

Comment: everytime the function executes the variable `i` is incremented by 1. This variable is then applied to the css value so that on first run the value is '1deg', then '2deg', then '3deg' and so on. I've not bothered to reset `i` when it reaches 360 but @remibreton's answer shows this.

Comment: http://maxime-senterre.infographie-heaj.be/sonarclock/ this is online, however doesn't turn i got an illegal token error on js and the css transition is auto disabled

Comment: you've got an illegal character after the final `;` (but it's somehow invisible). Just go to the end of that line and hit backspace. It will look like nothing happened but the script will now execute

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing with `var srotate = "rotate(1deg)";` is setting the rotation to 1 degree every 3 milliseconds. You need to *add* one degree per 3 ms.

Try this to iterate through the degrees until 360:

```
var degree = 1; // Declare outside your interval loop
setInterval(function(){ // Add this to your loop
    degree++;
    if(degree % 360 == 0){
        degree = 1;
    }
    var str = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'; // str now equals your string for transforms.
});
```

[Read more here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html) on transforms.

[Read more here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm) on modulus (%) operator.

Because of script execution, your 'clock' might delay on the long run when using setInterval. [More on this here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are using some CSS3 rules in your example, here is some pure CSS3 one: http://jsfiddle.net/semencov/RkysX/